# Authentication problem when installing something

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

The command fails due to credentials problems, but when you test with `kubectl get nodes` everything looks fine.

Output of `helm install`:

```
⋊> ~/t/mtltech on master ⨯ helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true                                                                                                   00:31:41
Error: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

Output of `kubectl get nodes`:

```
⋊> ~/t/mtltech on master ⨯ kubectl get nodes                                                                                                                                                               00:37:41
NAME                                       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
gke-mtltech-default-pool-977ee0b2-5lmi   Ready     <none>    7h        v1.11.7-gke.4
gke-mtltech-default-pool-977ee0b2-hi4v   Ready     <none>    7h        v1.11.7-gke.4
gke-mtltech-default-pool-977ee0b2-mjiv   Ready     <none>    7h        v1.11.7-gke.4
```

Output of `helm version`:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Output of `kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.7-gke.4", GitCommit:"618716cbb236fb7ca9cabd822b5947e298ad09f7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-05T19:22:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.7b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Cloud Provider:  `Google Cloud`

I've tried to reset it several times with `rm -rf ~/.helm && helm init --service-account tiller` but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the Tiller. I do not know how you deployed Helm and Tiller, but the mistake was there.

I used this chart and all works correctly, then I deleted my service account and cluster role binding and I met the same error - deleting only cluster role binding gives error:

`Error: release nginx-ingress failed: namespaces "default" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:tiller" cannot get namespaces in the namespace "default"`

So the error is due to missing Service Account or both.

Solution for this:
`rm -rf ~/.helm`

`kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system`

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule \
 --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
 --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
```

`helm init --service-account=tiller`

`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

check the full name of tiller pod:

`kubectl delete pod -n kube-system tiller-deploy-xxx`

Wait till the tiller pod will be redeployed and install your helm chart:

`helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true`